# Run command prompt as admin?

Tags: excel, vba

I need the command prompt to run as admin (it doesnt right now). I've seen solutions online but they all use slightly different setups and I dare not change more than necessary as this code is used in other parts as well that i dont have access to. I also cannot wait for user input as this is part of scripts that are batched together with other script.

Thank you for any help!

The relevant part of my code:

```
    'setting up cmd as a string above this code

    'Create the shell and send the python command
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    wsh.run cmd, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
End Sub
```